# Developing Speech to Text for messaging, Android

Tags: android

I'm kind of new in developing Android Application. I have a project in developing Speech to text for messaging sort of like the application called "Vlingo" and the application I'm developing also uses Text to Speech (TTS) API for reading incoming messages. So far I'm learning how to develop a simple application for Speech to Text and Text to Speech from these tutorials;

[Speech To Text](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/)

[Text to Speech](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-text-to-speech-application.html)

So from these tutorial, how do I integrate it with messaging? or the tutorial have nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own SMS application. For many phones you can already use speech-to-text while writing a new message. But there s no way you can integrate tts in default SMS application